# not able to get data result for oracle sql when run for different month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have a query as below

```
SELECT *
FROM   PEOPLE P, ACTION A
WHERE  ACT_YEARMONTH = PEO_YEARMONTH
  AND  ACT_GIN = PEO_GIN
  AND  PEO_YEARMONTH='2014/07'
```

when i am running for yearmonth `2014/06`. it is able to fetch data. But when i run for `2014/07`, then it is not able to fetch data. the combination of `GIN and yearmonth` data is present in both tables. 
On column `act_yearmonth, peo_yearmonth` are partitioned columns. 
*What is the reason the while sql is not fetching the data?*

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that the combination is *not* in the table.  If you think differently, you can put up an example on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: i saw combination(yearmonth and GIN) is present in both tables. that is my strange thinking.

Comment: Try `PEO_YEARMONTH LIKE '2014/07%'` perhaps? Please use table aliases as we have no idea which table holds which field, and do use ANSI join syntax.  Otherwise it's pretty clear '2014/07' does not exists in both.

Comment: In table people, though i have 150000 records, under partition tab, it says 0 records for yearmonth 2014/07. What does that mean?

Comment: @user1468031 - Not knowing what tool you're using or what "under partition tab" means in that particular tool, that result and the fact that your query isn't returning results strongly implies that there is no data in the table with that `peo_yearmonth`.  Is `peo_yearmonth` a `varchar2` column?  Or is it a `date`?  Or something else?

Comment: I am using TOAD Oracle tool. One of table ACTION table, i got data, but under partition tab, it says zero records. what does that mean? and also version of oracle 11g